# QT GUI freezes even though Im running in separate thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small chat application where I use a SQLite database to store all the conversations. I've noticed that the app freezes randomly, and I then have to minimize and maximize it to make it work again. I thought that the problem might be the SQLite selects / inserts that were causing the gui to freeze. I decided to try and move all the SQLite methods into a separate thread.

After doing so the app still freezes.

Some things that might be worth knowing:

1. I use `QTcpSocket` directly in my `MainWindow` but it seems that there is no use in running the `QTcpSocket` in a separate thread?
2. I have separated the SQLite methods into a new thread (see implementation below)
3. I use 3 `WebViews` for displaying my chat messages, the entire application GUI is build with these `WebViews`

Does my code below really run in a separate thread? GUI still freezes.

My header file:

```
class dbThread : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     dbThread(QObject* parent);

public slots:
     bool openDB(QString agentID);

signals:
     void clearPreviousHistory();

private:
     QSqlDatabase db;
     QHash<QString, QString> countries;
};
```

My cpp file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
QThread* thread = new QThread(this);
dbtrad = new dbThread(this);
dbtrad->moveToThread(thread);

dbtrad->openDB(userID);

connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(clearPreviousHistory()), this, SLOT(clearHistoryV()));
thread->start();

}



dbThread::dbThread(QObject * parent): QObject(parent) {
}

bool dbThread::openDB(QString agentID) {

    qDebug() << "OPEN DB FROM THREAD ";

    // Find QSLite driver
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    // ......
}
```

This is how I call `dbThread` methods from my `MainWindow`:

```
dbtrad->getHistory(channelId);
```

**Edit**

New code:

```
// Start database thread
QThread* thread = new QThread(this);
dbtrad = new dbThread(this);
dbtrad->moveToThread(thread);

connect(this, SIGNAL(requestOpenDB(QString)), dbtrad, SLOT(openDB(QString)));
thread->start();

emit requestOpenDB(userID);
```

Comment: show code where u call dbthread functions. Also do you call them from main thread ? you may be misinterpreting what `moveToThread` does.

Comment: See my edit, I've posted how I call db methods from my main thread

Comment: [QThread::currentThreadId () **Warning:** The handle returned by this function is used for internal purposes and should not be used in any application code.
**Warning:** On Windows, the returned value is a pseudo-handle for the current thread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#currentThreadId)

Comment: The true question is. Does it still freeze?

Comment: Before I do all updates (many methods) I wanted to make sure that its really running in a different thread. Is there another way to verify it?

Comment: @Alosyius give the new thread a name and call `qDebug()<<"function <function> called from: "<<QThread::currentThread()->objectName();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbtrad->openDB(userID);` will execute like any normal function (Why should it?), ***in the GUI thread***.

`moveToThread` allow you to ***execute slots called using signals*** in a separate thread.

If you want to execute `openDB` in the thread you can trigger its execution using

```
 connect (thread, SIGNAL(started()), dbtrad, SLOT(openDBWithUIDAlreadySet()))
```

or

```
 connect (this, SIGNAL(requestOpenDB(int)), dbtrad, SLOT(openDB(int)))
```

You need to use existing or additional signals. `Qthread::start()` emit the signal `started()`. You can also define

```
MainWindow{

signals:
    void  requestOpenDB(int);
    void queryHistory(int channelid);
}
```

and emit the signals manually using

```
emit requestOpenDB(userID);    //for openDB
emit queryHistory(channelId);  // for getHistory
```

the responses from the `dbThread` object also need to be given using a signal which is connected to a slot. Like a notification.

Comment: Ahhh I see! I'll update all my db calls with connects and see if that works

Comment: How would I make this call with a connect instead?  `dbtrad->getHistory(channelId);`

Comment: I tried printing out: `qDebug() << this->thread()->currentThreadId();`  both from inside MainWindow and inside the thread and I get same result: `0x7fff7300f180`

Comment: with the code you posted you are still inside the main GUI thread. You need to show the new code.

Answer (score 0):

1. `QTcpSocket`does indeed not need to be in a separated thread.
2. as long as all the database access is done from that thread where the database was created it should also be no problem
3. And now to the fun part: i think you create the database in the main thread ... by calling `dbtrad->openDB(userId)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes so qt `moveToThread()` does not do what you are expecting it to do. The function that you are calling from your main thread will get executed in your main thread only. That database access is causing GUI freezes.

`moveToThread` only moves "event processing" in a seperate thread. Which means any slots of `dbThread` which are connected using `Qt::QueuedConnection`will get executed in new thread.

Following way will execute `getHistory()` method in your main ui thread only. You need to create a signal in main thread and make `getHistory()` a slot of `dbThread` class. Then connect both.

Answer (score 0):

Reading documentation AND logs is essential!!!
In log you have a warning that YOU CAN"T MOVE TO THREAD IF OBJECT HAVE A PARENT.
Also [documentation clearly says that](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#moveToThread):

> Changes the thread affinity for this object and its children. **The
>   object cannot be moved if it has a parent**. Event processing will
>   continue in the targetThread.

---

Proper way to fix it:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    thread = new QThread(this);
    dbtrad = new dbThread(); // NO PARENT
    dbtrad->moveToThread(thread);

    // run object method in thread assigned to this object:
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(dbtrad, "openDB", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QString, userID));

    connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(clearPreviousHistory()), this, SLOT(clearHistoryV()));
    thread->start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    dbtrad->deleteLater();
    thread->quit();
    thread->wait(5000); // wait max 5 seconds to terminate thread
}
```

Comment: How can this be fixed? Not sure I know what to change to make it to work

Comment: do not set parent, see edit. You should also connect `dbtrad->openDB` to some signal from main window and pass `userID` this way, or do it like I did it by using meta data invoke.