# Qt GUI hangs despite threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have a Qt GUI application which does some I/O bound work when a button is pressed. In order to avoid GUI not being responsive, I created a new thread and move the work there:

```cpp
private slots:
    inline void on_process_button_clicked() const
    {
        std::thread thread(&My_class::on_process_button_clicked_real_work, this);
        thread.detach();
    }
```

I detach the thread immediately. The other function simply does the real work:

```cpp
void on_process_button_clicked_real_work() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    // Some irrelevant code ...
}
```

The GUI now doesn't entirely freeze, I can still see it updated, but it becomes really unresponsive and laggy.

Questions:
    1. Why does this happen?
    2. How may I fix it?

I have seen [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52081003/10147399) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23800709/10147399) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11426335/10147399), but most are about `QThread` so I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191800/discussion-on-question-by-ayxan-qt-gui-hangs-despite-threading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem is I was using `QFileSystemModel` (not in this function but in general) to show a list of files in the folder and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252175/10147399) answer points out:

> `QFileSystemModel` lists directories on a background thread to avoid
>   blocking the UI. However, once it gets a list of updates in
>   `QFileSystemModelPrivate::_q_fileSystemChanged` it then fetches the
>   icons for the file in the main thread using
>   `QFileInfoGatherer::getInfo()` which in turn calls
>   `QFileIconProvider::icon(QFileInfo)`.

The problem is that `QFileSystemModel` constantly updates the GUI while the new thread rapidly creates/removes files and that causes the laggy experience. I don't know how to stop or delay updates in that model, but what I did is changing `rootPath` to `""` and changing it back once the function finishes the work:

```
void on_process_button_clicked_real_work() const
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    auto path = model.rootPath();
    model.setRootPath("");

    // Some irrelevant code ...

    model.setRootPath(path);
}
```

Implementing some kind of lock object to be exception safe and make sure the `rootPath` is set back is probably the most optimal way.

Comment: If `model` is your QFSM, you are not allowed to touch it outside the GUI thread, no matter what's the amount of locking you put on it. You need to "disable" it from the GUI thread itself.

Comment: @peppe and how do I disable it?

Comment: Either from the function that spawns the thread (so, basically, from the GUI thread itself). Or, emit signals / use queued invocations from the worker thread.

Comment: @peppe is there a way to disable QFSM other than altering the rootPath?